Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' with EmbeddedId
I got this problem, i got error Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'
 ERROR LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory:426 - Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Column mappings for property 'null' mix nullable with 'not null'
2024-12-23 07:33:37.207  ERROR SpringApplication.reportFailure:824 - Application run failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Column mappings for property 'null' mix nullable with 'not null'

I've tried to check the database and model it has same nonnull
Here is my script for SQL
-- Create TEMP_PROJECT_WBS_SESSION table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_project_wbs_session (
    session_id serial4 PRIMARY KEY,
    project_wbs_id INT NOT NULL,
    user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    status VARCHAR(255),
    FOREIGN KEY (project_wbs_id) REFERENCES project_wbs(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

-- Create TEMP_PROJECT_WBS table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_project_wbs (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    session_id INT NOT NULL,
    project_id INT NOT NULL,
    status VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id, session_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (project_id) REFERENCES project(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

-- Create TEMP_PROJECT_WBS_TABS table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_project_wbs_tabs (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    session_id INT NOT NULL,
    temp_project_wbs_id INT NOT NULL,
    temp_parent_tabs_id INT,
    tab_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    order_no INT NOT NULL,
    level INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, session_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (temp_project_wbs_id, session_id) REFERENCES temp_project_wbs(id, session_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (temp_parent_tabs_id, session_id) REFERENCES temp_project_wbs_tabs(id, session_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

-- Create TEMP_PROJECT_WBS_TASK table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_project_wbs_task (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    session_id INT NOT NULL,
    project_id INT NOT NULL,
    temp_project_wbs_tabs_id INT NOT NULL,
    temp_project_wbs_parent_task_id INT,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    period INT,
    order_no INT,
    start_date DATE,
    end_date DATE,
    description TEXT,
    type VARCHAR(50),
    level INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, session_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (temp_project_wbs_tabs_id, session_id) REFERENCES temp_project_wbs_tabs(id, session_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (temp_project_wbs_parent_task_id, session_id) REFERENCES temp_project_wbs_task(id, session_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (project_id) REFERENCES project(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

-- Create TEMP_PROJECT_WBS_TASK_LINK table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_project_wbs_task_link (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    session_id INT NOT NULL,
    temp_project_wbs_id INT NOT NULL,
    temp_project_wbs_task_id INT NOT NULL,
    task_id INT NOT NULL,
    type VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (id, session_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (temp_project_wbs_id, session_id) REFERENCES temp_project_wbs(id, session_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (temp_project_wbs_task_id, session_id) REFERENCES temp_project_wbs_task(id, session_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (task_id, session_id) REFERENCES temp_project_wbs_task(id, session_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

-- Create TEMP_PROJECT_WBS_TASK_OUTPUT table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_project_wbs_task_output (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    session_id INT NOT NULL,
    temp_project_wbs_id INT NOT NULL,
    temp_project_wbs_task_id INT NOT NULL,
    standard_output_id INT,
    type VARCHAR(50),
    product_name VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id, session_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (temp_project_wbs_id, session_id) REFERENCES temp_project_wbs(id, session_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (temp_project_wbs_task_id, session_id) REFERENCES temp_project_wbs_task(id, session_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

-- Create TEMP_PROJECT_WBS_TASK_PIC table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_project_wbs_task_pic (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    session_id INT NOT NULL,
    temp_project_wbs_task_id INT NOT NULL,
    user_id INT,
    rate INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, session_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (temp_project_wbs_task_id, session_id) REFERENCES temp_project_wbs_task(id, session_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

Here is it my models Embedded Id
@Setter
@Getter
@Embeddable
public class TempPrimaryKey {

    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private BigInteger id; //mainId

    @Column(name = "session_id", nullable = false)
    private Integer sessionId;

    // Default constructor
    public TempPrimaryKey() {}

    // Constructor
    public TempPrimaryKey(BigInteger id, Integer sessionId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.sessionId = sessionId;
    }

    // Override equals() and hashCode()
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        TempPrimaryKey that = (TempPrimaryKey) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, that.id) && Objects.equals(sessionId, that.sessionId);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, sessionId);
    }
}

Here is it for WbsSession
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "temp_project_wbs_session")
public class TempProjectWbsSession extends BaseEntity {
    public static final String NEW_STATUS = "NEW";
    public static final String EDIT_STATUS = "EDIT";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "session_id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_wbs_id", nullable = false)
    private ProjectWbs projectWbs;

    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private Integer userId;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;
}

Here is it for Wbs
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "temp_project_wbs")
public class TempProjectWbs extends BaseEntity {
    @EmbeddedId
    private TempPrimaryKey id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", nullable = false)
    private Project project;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tempProjectWbs")
    @OrderBy("level ASC, orderNo ASC")
    private List<TempProjectWbsTab> tempProjectWbsTabs = new ArrayList<>();

}

Here is it for WbsTab
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "temp_project_wbs_tabs")
public class TempProjectWbsTab extends BaseEntity {
    @EmbeddedId
    private TempPrimaryKey id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "temp_project_wbs_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "session_id", referencedColumnName = "session_id", nullable = false)
    })
    private TempProjectWbs tempProjectWbs;

    @Column(name = "tab_name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "order_no", nullable = false)
    private Integer orderNo;

    @Column(name = "level", nullable = false)
    private Integer level;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "temp_parent_tabs_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "session_id", referencedColumnName = "session_id", nullable = false)
    })
    private TempProjectWbsTab tempParentTabs;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tempParentTabs")
    @OrderBy("orderNo ASC")
    private List<TempProjectWbsTab> childs = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tempProjectWbsTab")
    @OrderBy("level ASC, orderNo ASC")
    private List<TempProjectWbsTask> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

}

Here is it for Task
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "temp_project_wbs_task")
public class TempProjectWbsTask extends BaseEntity {
    public static final String TYPE_TASK = "TASK";
    public static final String TYPE_TAB = "TAB";
    public static final String TYPE_ACTIVITY = "ACTIVITY";

    @EmbeddedId
    private TempPrimaryKey id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", nullable = false)
    private Project project;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "temp_project_wbs_tabs_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "session_id", referencedColumnName = "session_id", nullable = false)
    })
    private TempProjectWbsTab tempProjectWbsTab;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "period")
    private Integer period = 0;

    @Column(name = "order_no")
    private Integer orderNo;

    @Column(name = "start_date")
    private LocalDate startDate;

    @Column(name = "end_date")
    private LocalDate endDate;

    @Column(name = "description", length = Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    private String description;

    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "type", length = 50)
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "level")
    private Integer level;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "temp_project_wbs_parent_task_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "session_id", referencedColumnName = "session_id", nullable = false)
    })
    private TempProjectWbsTask tempProjectWbsParentTask;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tempProjectWbsParentTask")
    @OrderBy("orderNo ASC")
    private List<TempProjectWbsTask> childs = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tempProjectWbsTask", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<TempProjectWbsTaskLink> tempProjectWbsTaskLinker = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tempProjectWbsTask", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<TempProjectWbsTaskOutput> tempProjectWbsTaskOutputs = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tempProjectWbsTask", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<TempProjectWbsTaskPic> tempProjectWbsPics = new ArrayList<>();

    public LocalDate getStartDate() {
        if (TYPE_TASK.equals(this.type))
            return this.startDate;
        return this.childs.stream()
                .map(TempProjectWbsTask::getStartDate)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .min(LocalDate::compareTo)
                .orElse(this.startDate);
    }

    public LocalDate getEndDate() {
        if (TYPE_TASK.equals(this.type))
            return this.endDate;
        return this.childs.stream()
                .map(TempProjectWbsTask::getEndDate)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .max(LocalDate::compareTo)
                .orElse(this.endDate);
    }

    public String getTaskCode() {
        if (this.tempProjectWbsParentTask == null) {
            return String.valueOf(this.orderNo);
        } else {
            return this.tempProjectWbsParentTask.getTaskCode() + "." + this.orderNo;
        }
    }
}

Here is it for TaskLink
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "temp_project_wbs_task_link")
public class TempProjectWbsTaskLink extends BaseEntity {
    @EmbeddedId
    private TempPrimaryKey id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "temp_project_wbs_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "session_id", referencedColumnName = "session_id", nullable = false)
    })
    private TempProjectWbs tempProjectWbs;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "temp_project_wbs_task_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "session_id", referencedColumnName = "session_id", nullable = false)
    })
    private TempProjectWbsTask tempProjectWbsTask; //projectWbsTask -> linkedTo task (FS, FF, SS, SF)

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "task_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "session_id", referencedColumnName = "session_id", nullable = false),
    })

    private TempProjectWbsTask task;

    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "type", length = 50)
    private String type;

}

Here is it for TaskOutput
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "temp_project_wbs_task_output")
public class TempProjectWbsTaskOutput extends BaseEntity {
    @EmbeddedId
    private TempPrimaryKey id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "temp_project_wbs_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "session_id", referencedColumnName = "session_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private TempProjectWbs tempProjectWbs;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "temp_project_wbs_task_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "session_id", referencedColumnName = "session_id", nullable = false)
    })
    private TempProjectWbsTask tempProjectWbsTask;

    @ManyToOne
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "standard_output_id", nullable = false)
    private StandardOutputView standardOutput;

    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "type", length = 50)
    private String type;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "product_name")
    private String outputName;
}

Here is it for TaskPic
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "temp_project_wbs_task_pic")
public class TempProjectWbsTaskPic extends BaseEntity {
    public static final String TYPE_PM = "TYPEPM";
    public static final String TYPE_INDIVIDUAL_ASSIGNEE = "TYPEINDIVIDUAL";
    public static final String TYPE_BY_ROLE = "TYPEROLE";

    @EmbeddedId
    private TempPrimaryKey id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "temp_project_wbs_task_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "session_id", referencedColumnName = "session_id", nullable = false)
    })
    private TempProjectWbsTask tempProjectWbsTask;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private UserView user;

    @Column(name = "rate")
    private Integer rate;
}


This question is similar to: Confusion: @NotNull vs. @Column(nullable = false) with JPA and Hibernate. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Have you read the error? The error is pretty clear -> Column mappings for property 'null' mix nullable with 'not null' you have a column mapping which in one entity is marked os not null while in another is it is marked as nullable. Probably if you check the full stacktrace it will exactly tell you which entity and property, but checking the whole bunch of code it concerns the TempProjectWbsTaskOutput and the tempProjectWbs field. That is not marked as nullable=false which is thus using the default of nullable=true. That is conflicting column definitions.
